# Avoid MCR CACHE deletion each time an executable is launched

Tags: matlab, caching, matlab-compiler

I have two Matlab scripts (Init.m and Filter.m) compiled using the Matlab application compiler in Windows (Init.exe and Filter.exe are created). I have seen that if I launch the Init.exe, a folder is created in the MCR_CACHE folder containing all the necessary files to run Init.exe. If I launch Init.exe again the time to execute it reduces dramatically since its folder in MCR_CACHE folder has already been created. Now, if I launch the Filter.exe, the folder of the Init.exe in the MCR_CACHE is deleted and a folder for the Filter.exe in the MCR_CACHE is created. How can I avoid the deletion of the Init.exe folder in the MCR_CACHE? This way if I launched Init.exe after having launched the Filter.exe, the Init.exe execution would be much faster.

Comment: Seing that this is something that MATLAB does automatically, its likely that the answer is no. If you could control it, maybe you could make a cache folder per-executable, but I think this is part of internal MATLAB works. You could always have a folder for each executable (instead of having them share the folder, thus overwritting each other)